# Dynamically switch to different firebase project apps using (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am working on firebase using javascript
how to switch to different apps
I have two-dimensional array the first array has firebase app information like api_key app id storage path etc and inner array have 10 files that I want to upload on firebase storage then store download URL of that files in a database on firebase. first iteration for the firebase config file and inner iteration for upload file on firebase storage.but after the first iteration of the loop that firebase gives an error
"code: "app/duplicate-app", message: "Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)"
my question is that how to switch different apps dynamically in firebase

async  function uploadFiles(app_data1) {

```
$.each(app_data1,function(i,app){

    var api_key=app.fire_base_data.api_key;
    var database=app.fire_base_data.firebasePath;
    var storage=app.fire_base_data.firebaseStoragePath;
    var config = {
  apiKey: api_key,
  //  authDomain: "<your-project-id>.firebaseapp.com",  
  databaseURL: database,
  storageBucket: storage,
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

    $.each(app.app_data,function(i,file){


    //console.log(app.app_name+","+"app file: "+app.backup_file_path);
    var d = new Date();
    const my_date=d.getDay()+"-"+d.getMonth()+"-"+d.getFullYear();
    var tabl_name =file.replace(".sql", "");
    const new_name=tabl_name+"_"+my_date+".sql";
    var backup_path="daily-backup/"+app.fire_base_data.app_name+"/"+file;
    console.log(backup_path);

    const ref = firebase.storage().ref('backup/'+my_date+"/"+new_name);
        //console.log(backup_path+":"+app_data.app_id);  
        toDataUrl(backup_path, function(myBase64) {
         var upload_task= ref.putString(myBase64, 'data_url').then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log( file+": "+snapshot.totalBytes);
        count++
        const  metadata = snapshot.metadata;
        const  Url=snapshot.downloadURL;
        const  percentage = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
        if (percentage==100) {
          //console.log(Url);
          const  rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
          const  storesRef = rootRef.child('backup/'+app.fire_base_data.app_name);
          const  table_ref=storesRef.child(tabl_name+"/");
          table_ref.child(my_date+"/").set({'file_name':new_name,'download url':Url});
          //deleteDirectory(backup_path)

        }

      });    
       });
      });

     });


}
```

code: "app/duplicate-app", message: "Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).", name: "[DEFAULT]", stack: "[DEFAULT]: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]…com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js:2:81117)

Answer (score 0):

Once you call [initializeApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#initialize-app), you can't call it again (with the same app name) until you call [delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App.html#delete) on the app that was initialized.  What you're trying to do now is initialize an app with the same name as a previously initialized app, which is invalid.

If you want to have multiple initialized apps available at the same time, you should give them unique names using the second argument to [initializeApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#initialize-app).

Comment: thanks, @Doug Stevenson, I have an array of different apps and I want to push file according to that apps . is there any way initialize multiple apps like in a loop